# How to make my random number unique and sort the number

Tags: java, arrays, random

I use collection shuffle but it doesn't work so far I go with this.

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;

public class TotoMachine {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] array = new int[7];
        Random rand = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
            array[i] = rand.nextInt(65) + 1;
        //Collections.shuffle()
        Arrays.sort(array);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly you are trying to do, inserting random number itself is sufficient, no need to shuffle them again.

Comment: but my output number might be repeat only shuffle can make it unique right ?

Comment: suppose you need to check the array for existing numbers and insert only if its new.

Comment: Yes, but you are printing numbers after Arrays.sort(array); that will sort them anyway, so shuffle will not have any importance.

Comment: Suffle will not make it unique, you need to use set or manually check

Comment: I am done with sorting, now the unique part my output number might repeat i don't wan it to become same number what should i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

suppose you can try like this as a work around.
Hope you are familiar with `List`.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
           List<Integer> array = new ArrayList<Integer>();
           Random rand = new Random();
           int num;
           for (int i = 0; array.size() < 7 ; i++){

               num = rand.nextInt(65) + 1;
               if(!array.contains(num)){
                   array.add(num);
               }
           }

           Collections.sort(array);
           System.out.println(array.toString());
           }    
}
```

Comment: This might give you less than 7 numbers, if a number is generated twice

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Set<Integer> set = new TreeSet<>();
    Random rand = new Random();
    while (set.size() < 7)
        set.add(rand.nextInt(65) + 1);
    System.out.println(set);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work: Add random number generated to a Set untill some size. Then convert it to Array like this:

```
import java.util.*;

class random{
    public static void main(String[] args){
    int max=65;
    int min=0;
    int size=7;

    Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>();
    Random random = new Random(); 
    while(set.size()<size){
        int randomNum = random.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
        set.add(randomNum);
    }
    Integer[] intArray= set.toArray(new Integer[set.size()]);
    Arrays.sort(intArray);
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
        System.out.println(intArray[i]+" ");    
    }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `Set` to achieve unique numbers. For example you could try this:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Set;

public class TotoMachine {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] array = new int[7];
        Random rand = new Random();
        Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();
        while (set.size() < array.length) {
            set.add(rand.nextInt(65) + 1);
        }
        int i = 0;
        for (Integer integer : set) {
            array[i] = integer;
            i++;
        }
        Arrays.sort(array);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
    }
}
```

If you have any chance to use the already created `set`, do so instead of converting it to an `int[]` array. If you are free to use an `Integer[]` instead of an `int[]`, you could convert it like this:

```
Integer[] arr = new Integer[7];
set.toArray(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use `Collections`, specifically `Set`(s). You might create a [`LinkedHashSet<Integer>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html) and add your desired number of random values. Then you might add those values to a [`TreeSet<Integer>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) (which is *sorted*). Something like,

```
Random rand = new Random();
final int SIZE = 7;
Set<Integer> set = new LinkedHashSet<>(SIZE);
while (set.size() < SIZE) {
    set.add(rand.nextInt(65) + 1);
}
System.out.println(set);
Set<Integer> sortedSet = new TreeSet<>(set);
System.out.println(sortedSet);
```

**or** you could use streams and a `Collector` like

```
List<Integer> list = set.stream().sorted().collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(list);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Set` data structure to make unique random numbers in this way:

> Add every new random elements to the `Set` then you only add it to the
>   array if it's unique element.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] array = new int[7];
    int randomNum;
    Set<Integer> numbers = new HashSet<>(); //Set of unique elements
    Random rand = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
        randomNum = rand.nextInt(65) + 1;
        numbers.add(randomNum);
        if(!numbers.contains(randomNum)){ // if unique element add it to array
            array[i] = randomNum;
        }
        else{    // keep generating new random numbers until you get unique element
            while(numbers.contains(randomNum)){
                randomNum = rand.nextInt(65) + 1;
            }
            numbers.add(randomNum);
            array[i] = randomNum;
        }
     }
    Arrays.sort(array);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));            
}
```

I hope this would solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

if not using a set: You might do something like this.

Generate random number.

Check array to see if random number exists

If not exists -- insert random number into array.

If exists generate new random number and repeat the above steps.

Do this until your array is populated to capacity.

This method can be made alot sweeter with recursion.

Otherwise use sets: sets do not contain any duplicates.

You can then convert your set to an array as some examples show.